# How to do distcp from cloudera to hortonwork

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

I'm trying to distcp from from cloudera to hortonwork, But getting following error.
I tried with webhdfs and hftp, but no luck.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea62T.png)
Could someone help me on this one

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Namenode REST/webui port. 8088 is YARN Resource manager web ui port, which cannot be used here. Update the source path as follows,

```
webhdfs://192.168.38.131:50070/ashish/data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on target cluster where you want to get the data, 
So from target cluster are you able to make webhdfs call hftp call to source cluster

If yes then only you will be able to